# Logic behind creating a basketball simulator with Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning Python 3.x together with Flask. I'm also a Basketball fan, so I thought I'd be a good idea to get in the water and try to do a game simulator, perhaps only between two teams to begin with - and learn more Python along the way.

My biggest question for start is what should the logic behind the simulator be? Let's say I want to sim two historic teams - Lakers00 vs Bulls 98. Stats of the players are available online.

I want it to be "realistic," so perhaps getting into percentages of each player? If Jordan shot let's say 50% for the season - should that be programmed into each 'player' and then tell what's the chance that the % is higher or lower than that in each simulation? Should I use .json to store the data?

Or is there a completely different approach I should take?

Once the code is in, I would ideally try to turn that into a website with Flask. What database would you recommend to use?

Thank you

Comment: with programming - meaning learn along while you develop something fun

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you will want a to rig up a modifier to help compare teams from different eras. Defensive rules have changed over the ages and its had a great effect on field goal percentages, as have things like pace of play.

Comment: I would want to start simple, as I am still learning Python. And I would really just start with 2 teams, just to get an understanding on how things run and the logic behind it.

Comment: Start with teams from the same era then. However if you wanted to do a modifier it would be easy to make.

Just make a function that checks what era a team is from, and if it's from a certain era it modifies FG or total points. 
                                                    
If team in 90s_teams:                                     FG = FG * 1.01

Answer (score 0):

I don't know JSON, but I'd start with keeping it simple, if you're still working on this.

1: Players should have at least the following fields:
         Breakdown of possession usage (TO, 2 Pt shot, 3 pt shot)
         2 pt shooting percentage, 3 pt shooting percentage
2: I'd probably start by including something like usage percentage

The simplest way to do it would be have a player class with those attributes. If you took the advice of #2 you could use a function to pull out which player used the possession, and what they did with it (2 pt shot, 3 pt shot, turnover, and whether the shot was successful). Defense, rebounds, fouls might be more for later versions of the game, but if you start with that you'll at least have something that resembles basketball. I think NBA games are roughly 100 possessions.